# Compress H264 Stream Using Gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I am trying to create a GStreamer pipeline (**v 1.0**) in order to record and play special file format.

For recording purpose I use the following pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw-yuv, format=\(fourcc\)I420,  width=640, height=480 ! videoconvert ! x264enc byte-stream=1 ! queue ! appsink
```

In *appsink* (using new_sample() callback) I use a compression method to compress H264 stream and finally store in a output file.

I use the following pipeline to play the recorded file:

```
gst-launch-1.0 appsrc ! video/x-h264 ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

In *appsrc* I decompress H264 stream and send it to appsrc buffer (using push-buffer). The size of each buffer is 4095.

Unfortunately GStreamer after push 2 buffers print the following debug message:

*Error: Internal data flow error.*

Is there any way to fix the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add legacyh264parse or h264parse (depending on your version of gst components) before your decoder. You need to be able to send full frames to the decoder.
2. Post avdec_h264 it would be nice to have a ffmpegcolorspace to be able to convert the video format to your display requirements.

Comment: *[You need to be able to send full frames to the decoder.]* How can I do that?

Comment: that is what the "parse" elements are for. h264parse or legacyh264parse

Comment: As I mentioned before, "The size of each buffer is 4095". I mean, I read 4095 bytes from file and after decompression I push it to pipeline via Appsrc. As far as I understand from your answer, I should push each frame separately (Am I thinking right?). Now, How can I calculate the size of each frame to push?

Comment: @scatterbrain, See my previous previous comment. That is exactly something h264parse will take care off. Just add that element to the pipeline.  Also add ffmpegcolorspace at the end before the sink.